# Use autotools with README.md

Tags: c, github, autotools

I'm using autotools for a libraries hosted on GitHub. Instead of using an ordinary `README` text file, I want to use `README.md`.

When running `automake`, I get the following error

```
Makefile.am: required file `./README' not found
```

Is it possible to tell autotools not to check for `README`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just pass the `foreign` option to automake.  This tells it that your software does not conform to the typical gnu standards, and thus omitting README is not an error.  Typically, this is done in `configure.ac`:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
```

but it can also be done by assigning `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS` in Makefile.am:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Note for others, you need to run `autoreconf` after changing `configure.ac`.

Answer (score 7):

We are using

```
README: README.md
        fgrep -v "[Build Status]" $< \
                | markdown \
                | html2text -style pretty -nobs \
                | sed -e 's:&gt;:>:g' \
                > $@.tmp
```

to generate a text README from the markdown README.md

Comment: thank you! but why so complicated? Wouldn't a
README: README.md
    cat $< > $@.tmp
do? :)

Answer (score 7):

The simples solution, based pn [fceller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2098565/fceller)'s answer: The only thing that is needed, is a build rule for `README` in `makefile.am`. This rule can even be empty. So just add the following line to your `makefile.am`:

```
README: README.md
```

That's all, now automake does not complain anymore, and you don't need to declare your project as `foreign`.

It is not needed, but I prefer a more complete rule, I add to `makefile.am`:

```
README: README.md
    pandoc -f markdown -t plain --wrap=none $< -o $@

CLEANFILES = README
```

But even with this rule, `README` is not built unless you explicitly call `make README`.

Answer (score 5):

Why ask it not to look for your README file when you already have one? It just happens to be in markdown format and saved as README.md. If you want your README file to be identical to your README.md file, why not link to it?

From the command line:

```
ln -s README.md README
```

That way, you get to keep your README.md file and any tools you use will still be able to work with the standard naming conventions. Parenthetically speaking, it is very likely that autotools allows you to specify a custom path for your readme.

Answer (score 0):

automake 1.16.4 (from 2021) is now supposed to natively allow .md extension for a bunch of files, including getting `make dist` correct for those files.